# How to create a PloneFormGen validator for file types?

Tags: validation, plone, ploneformgen, plone-5.x

I'm creating a Plone form, using PloneFormGen, and I need a PDF file upload field. How can I write a validator that will test if the uploaded file is a PDF file, or if at least has a .pdf extension?

Comment: I need something similar for Plone 4. For now, I just need to test if a user has selected a file for uploading. It would also be useful to determine the type of file or the extension, and the file size. I have tried searching for several days, but cannot find anything. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: http://docs.plone.org/working-with-content/managing-content/ploneformgen/custom_validators.html

This is what you have, you can check the file from the request, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
python: test('.pdf' in value.filename, False, 'File must be a PDF')
```

To the PloneFormGen validator for each file upload item. This is a pretty simple check for .pdf. It's not ideal but does a simple string check. A better option would be to check the mime-type of the file on the server.